# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'soup'

Tags: python, attributes

I am just trying to print my raw text from bs4. However, I cant access the attribute from inside one of my methods. But I can access the attribute just fine from outside the class.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pp
import datetime
import time

stocklist = ["wish","clov","baba","pltr",'mu','nio','sofi','tsla','gme','clne',]
   
class Stock:
    
    def __init__(self,stocklist,s):
        self.address = Stock.AG(stocklist,s)
        self.soup = Stock.Soup(stocklist,s)
        self.volume = Stock.Volume(stocklist,s)
        self.price = Stock.Price(stocklist,s)
        
    def AG(stocklist,s):
        stockurl = str(('https://robinhood.com/stocks/'+stocklist[s]))
        return(stockurl)

    def Soup(stocklist,s):
        r = requests.get('https://robinhood.com/stocks/'+stocklist[s])
        soup = str(BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml'))
        return(soup)
    
    def Volume(stocklist,s):
        print(stocklist[s].soup) # does not work
    
    def Price(stocklist,s):
        pass
    
    
for s in range(len(stocklist)):
    stocklist[s] = Stock(stocklist,s)
    print(stocklist[s].address)
    print(stocklist[s].volume)
    print(stocklist[s].soup) #works
```

Comment: `def Soup(stocklist,s)` missing `self` parameter

Answer (score 0):

So this is because when you are calling the volume function stocklist[s] still refers to the string not to the object. Think about when you are calling the init method and hows it being called before the list is overwritten.

The very quick and dirty solution I came up with which should not be deployed but highlights the problem is to change you init method to this.

```
def __init__(self,stocklist,s):
    self.address = Stock.AG(stocklist,s)
    self.soup = Stock.Soup(stocklist,s)
    stocklist[s] = self
    self.volume = Stock.Volume(stocklist,s)
    self.price = Stock.Price(stocklist,s)
```